# Dart CSV Writing

Tags: csv, dart, flutter

Hey so I haven't really messed around with it too much, but I was wondering if there was actually a way (before I go down a neverending rabbit hole) to read and write to CSV files in Dart/Flutter? I need to write to the files, not necessarily read them, and I'm willing to go to quite extreme lengths to do so. Any library works, built-in functions are even better. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use package `csv` from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/csv

If you have a `List<List<dynamic>>` items that needs to convert into csv,

```
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(yourListOfLists);
```

If you want to write the csv to a file,

```
/// Write to a file
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final pathOfTheFileToWrite = directory.path + "/myCsvFile.csv";
File file = await File(pathOfTheFileToWrite);
file.writeAsString(csv);
```

Also, if you want to read a csv file directly into `list<list<dynamic>>`

```
final input = new File('a/csv/file.txt').openRead();
final fields = await input.transform(UTF8.decoder).transform(csvCodec.decoder).toList();
```

Comment: when inserting to a CSV file, how to specify which file exactly?

Comment: In the above example, the file is `a/csv/file.txt`. In an actual scenario, you can get your filepath from reading external storage directory or app directory. Use `path_provider` package for getting the directory path info. @Fethi

Comment: but in the first code you mentioned when inserting you didn't specify any path, how does it insert to a it ?

Comment: Updated the answer for the same @Fethi

Comment: How would you append more data to the existing sheet?
using `mode: FileMode.append` appends to the last entry without spaces or going to a new line, and doing `"$csv\n"` just gets overwritten by the next entry.

Answer (score 1):

According to new packages and guidelines(2019) use following code

package `csv`from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/csv.

If you have a `List<List<dynamic>>` items that needs to convert into csv,

```
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(yourListOfLists);
```

Then you can write the string to a file using file operations.

```
file.writeAsString('$csv');
```

Also, if you want to read a csv file directly into `list<list<dynamic>>`

```
final input = new File('a/csv/file.txt').openRead();
final fields = await input.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(new CsvToListConverter()).toList();
```