# How to save csv file into the internal storage downloads folder in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm generating a CSV file and saving like the following,

```
String dir = '';
if (Platform.isAndroid)
  dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path;
else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
}
File file = File("$dir/" +
    "test" +
    DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
    ".csv");
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
file.writeAsString(csv);
```

But I want to save it into the internal storage downloads folder. How can I do that? It's not a url file, it's generated in the app itself. How can I show that downloaded file in notification bar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54319575/5546443

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the (absolute) path to the Download folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776109/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-download-folder)

Comment: @krishnakumarcn see my file is saving now. But I wanted to save it in downloads folder.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider
This package can be of use to you. Even though they are internally using path_provider with some flags to get the downloads folder. But this will be a quicker solution.

Comment: @krishnakumarcn this one will work in iOS? wr it will save in iOS?

Comment: @krishnakumarcn and once it's download it won't show in notifier bar no...

Comment: Even though they are saying both iOS and Android supported, I'm not sure about the platform support for iOS. Also the github page of the library shows that they are not maintaining it.  My recommendation would be to use path_provider with a custom directory based code for ios or android.

Comment: My requirement is save into a downloads folder...

Comment: @krishnakumarcn downloads_path_provider this lib is working in debug..am not able to take release build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [path_provider_ex](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_ex) package

You can get an internal storage directory list as well as external storage(SD card) directories by using the above package

this package gives you a root directory, once you have a root directory you can access any folder from internal and external storage

Check out the example: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_ex/example

**Note**: *Dont forget to give access to storage permissions needed for accessing storage*